# if condition in laravel according to database columns

Tags: laravel-5

I have a day column in a database and I want to display the other columns according to the day.

```
@foreach($specialism as $item)
    @if($item->day ==="saturday")
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{url('button',['id'=>$item->id])}}">
            {{$item->name}}<br>
            {{$item->day}}<br>
            {{$item->from}}<br>
            {{$item->to}}
            </a>
        </td>
    @elseif($item->day === "sunday")
         <td>
             <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{url('button',['id'=>$item->id])}}">
             {{$item->name}}<br>
             {{$item->day}}<br>
             {{$item->from}}<br>
             {{$item->to}}
            </a>
         </td>
    @elseif($item->day === "monday")
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  href="{{url('button',['id'=>$item->id])}}">
            {{$item->name}}<br>
            {{$item->day}}<br>
            {{$item->from}}<br>
            {{$item->to}}
            </a>
        </td>
```

But it doesn't work. What's the problem??

Comment: Do each of your `$item` objects definitely have a `day` that is in lowercase?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: i have a table each td is a day of the week ,i want to display items each  under it's day which specified in database@JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: yes @ObsidianAge

Comment: @hala Maybe you forgot `@endforeach`

Comment: @hala What output do you want and what output you have right now?

Comment: it displays all the items that i want but not in the same order ,
the items displayed behind each other ,not according to the if conditional which according to the days of week .
i want to test the item's day if it's the same as in the condition prints,if not prints in the right one for it @Jonjie

Comment: @hala Right. Okay so, what do you get if you use `dd($specialism)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the data before you get to the foreach loop and then just echo out the html.

If you use a date field with a carbon instances you also have a nummeric representation of the weekday so you could use that, like:

```
$collection->sortBy(function($a, $b){
    return $a->date->day <=> $b->date->day; // date === carbon instance
});
```

If you only have a string representation you should get the weekday number by using either Carbon or PHP date, strtotime or DateTime and generate the number.

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters